# Super class/Super interface of Interface

Tags: inheritance, interface, extends, superclass

Whats is Super in Interface Hierarchy as Object class is the Super class of that that who does not Explicitly Extends any Class, which is the super of interface..??

Answer (score 0):

If an interface has no direct superinterfaces, then the interface implicitly declares a public abstract member method m with signature s, return type r, and throws clause t corresponding to each public instance

Comment: Consider formatting the relevant parts of your answer using the quote tool. I believe you simply prefix with >